# Webm HTML5 doesn't seem to be compatible with IOS safari

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari

I'm struggling to understand as to why it wouldn't be supported. My snippet is as follows:

```
<video autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay" class="maskfill" loop="loop" src="/videos/maskfill.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis"></video>
```

Is there any official reason for this? Or is there a recommended alternative? I've considered moving them over to MP4 but I'm doubtful of the lack of compression.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: [it is not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm). The reason is that iOS can only do hardware decoding [of a few codecs](http://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/videotoolbox/) (typically some H.264 profiles).

So, the recommended alternative is to use [H.264](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html).

Comment: I know. Is there a recommended alternative?

Comment: Fallback to MP4 (maintaining both on server) or maybe Flash when not supported?

Comment: Falling back to Flash is going to be bad for [many](http://www.wired.com/2015/07/adobe-flash-player-die/) [different](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-53/product_id-6761/Adobe-Flash-Player.html) [reasons](http://occupyflash.org). I guess the main one is that Flash is not supported on iOS